# Sinatra JSON being misread in Android App

Tags: android, ruby, json, sinatra

My Android JSON parser is giving the error when reading from Sinatra server.

```
E/JSON Parser(21872): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: 
Value <h1>Not of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.
```

Everything works fine when reading the same JSON from a PHP file on a different server.

It looks like Sinatra/Ruby is adding in some extra stuff even though the only thing that shows on the page is {"con":{"session":"001","token":"1234567890"}}

Am I doing something wrong on the server end that is causing this to happen?

Here is an example of what my main ruby app looks like:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'json'

class Example< Sinatra::Base
    get '/foobar.json' do
        content_type :json
        {:con =>{:session =>'001',:token =>'1234567890'}}.to_json
    end
end
```

Comment: What's the exact response?

Comment: in some cases you need to set the content type to application/json in your java code too

Comment: @IllegalArgument: I went ahead and added it but it didn't help. Also, everything works fine when pulling from a php file, just not when calling the Sinatra app.

Comment: @DaveNewton {"con":[{"session":"001","token":"1234567890"}]}

Comment: That's what's shown when you log the content response or view the source from the browser? in that case you'll need to actually show precisely how you're calling the page from the Android app, because if it's getting an `<h1>` tag you're probably not doing what you think you are, e.g., a post v. a get etc.

Comment: @DaveNewton Ah man I feel silly. It was GET Android side and POST Sinatra side. Got everything working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that on HttpClient object on the Android side was for Post rather than Get